# Make column a Query value

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I was wondering if it is possible to make a column in a table which equals with a query column with `MS Access`.

For example.
`QueryX` got a column called `'numbers'` which contains `1, 2, 3`.
Now I want `TableY` (which also have a column 'numbers') to copy these numbers directly from the Query so `TableY`. Numbers also contains `1, 2, 3`.
And when a number is added in the Query it also have to be added in the column.

Thanks,

Comment: should the TableY.Numbers column be overridden? or do you just want to add the values?

Comment: @JoJo TableY.Numbers has to be the QueryX.Numbers value. Always. There is notthing in the TableY except for Numbers. So if the Query changes the Table has to change too. Is that possible?

Comment: @JoJo excuse me. TableY contains 2 other columns which are also in in the Query.

Comment: Quick question, is QueryX the query to create TableY ?

Comment: can you show me your query? @Jesse?

Comment: @JoJo it is a big Query. The output are: Totalprice, BeginDate, EndDate. The info I need in the table are those 3.

Comment: Sounds like you need a simple MakeTable query based off your query.  Or, at the very least, an Update query which will update the table.  And, of course, how will you know **when** to run this Update query?  There are a lot of factors at play here that we don't know about, so I would suggest you edit your question and fill it with as much detail as possible.